# Trying to pull a long list of data from my MongoDB (abc.db)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

(this is for my discord.js bot with custom prefixes)

I have a ton of data saved in my database as {$guild.id}.prefix
I need to pull all the entries that are the prefixes of these guilds in one go. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
db.Collection.find( { guild.id: { $regex: /^prefix/ } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

db.collection.find(query, projection)